# P-values in orange data mining

Tags: orange

I'm new to orange and struggling to find p-values, using linear regression tools.

It seems the outputs are only coefficients. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orange mostly doesn't have p-values. We are generally against showing them, due to the Texas sharpshooter problem. You can read more about it [here](https://orange.biolab.si/blog/2019/1/4/how-to-abuse-p-values-in-correlations/).